# Calculating the Count of Unique Values in VBA which starts with a particular name

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to Identify the count of Unique Values in a column which starts with a particular name John.

How do you do this in VBA?

```
ColumnA   ColumnB
JohnRed   3
JohnBlue
JohnGreen
JohnRed   
IanRed
```

If you are looking for John. Then its 3.

Comment: You should find your answer here. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/count-unique-values-among-duplicates-8d9a69b3-b867-490e-82e0-a929fbc1e273

Comment: @Variatus Yes Sir, I read that before posting here. But they don't have it with the STARTS WITH Condition

Comment: That is part of the definition of the range within which you search. Will the formulas in the MSDN support do the job for you if we help you to define a range starting with "John"?

Comment: @Robin Mackenzie - It's unique values he wants to count, not repetitions.

Comment: @Variatus - no problem, misread question. Now I re-read it I am confused. Is it a range for a column with a header with value `John` or a range where the values are prefixed with `John` and I want to count the number of times `John_foo` occurs ?

Comment: @VBA_Begineer - can you update your question with an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Variatus I couldn't Understand what you are saying sir. I have updated my question with an example now. Please check it.

Comment: Your example isn't clear. There are 2 different "John..." but there are also 2 "JohnRed". Which 2 is in column B?

Comment: It will be impossible to determine "John" in "JohnRed" without knowing one or the other of the components. Can you provide a list of the colours, if not a list of possible names? It would be different if you have "John Red" and "Ian Red" with the first word always being the one to count as unique.

Comment: @Variatus Its two because, there is JohnRed, JohnBlue for John. There are no list of Colors predefined. The list of the names will be populating Programatically everytime and therefore there are no pre-defined lists. Suppose if there is JohnGreen as well inside the column then the Count will become 3 for John as there are 3 Unique Values for John Inside the Column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to read the value from the `Range`, and compare with `"John*"`. Later use a `Dictionary` to count the unique `Keys`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub UniqueJohns()

Dim JohnsArr As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim Dict As Object
Dim Result As Long

Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

' read into array, to run faster
JohnsArr = Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A5"))

' loop through array elements
For i = 1 To UBound(JohnsArr)
    If JohnsArr(i) Like "John*" Then
        ' check if already exists in Dictionary
        If Not Dict.exists(JohnsArr(i)) Then
            Dict.Add JohnsArr(i), JohnsArr(i)
        End If
    End If
Next i
Result = UBound(Dict.keys) ' <-- this is the result, unique keys in Dictionary
MsgBox Result

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Sir ! I can alter this for my requirement.